# How to expand using of trim() and replace() for multiple tables and columns

Tags: mysql, replace, trim

I have **20 table** that each of the tables has **20 columns**. The type of the all columns are varchar. I want to use `replace()` and `trim()` in MySQL. Something like this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET col1 = TRIM(REPLACE(`col1`, 'x', 'y' ));
```

Now I'm looking for a way to do that as generalized. In fact I can't use of the above query for all tables and columns (20*20=400 times). Is it possible to I expand above query for all tables and columns ?

In other word, How can I use `*` for select all columns into `trim()` or `replace()` ?

Comment: Use the schema tables and generate a script dynamically. There's no macro facility in SQL.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks, But I think I can't generate a script dynamically in sql.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start. MySQL isn't my specialty but the general idea should work.

```
select
    concat(
        'update ', table_name, ' set ',
        group_concat(
            concat( column_name, ' = trim(replace(', column_name, ', ''x'', ''y''))' )
        )
    )
from information_schema.columns
group by table_name
```

Comment: `table_name` and `column_name` are manually ? what difference is between my query and your solution ?

Comment: I think that I should use a `array();` included all name of tables . and then get name of columns for each table (I don't know how, maby something like this `information_schema.columns`). and then run that `array();` intro my codes. Can you implement it ?

Comment: You don't need an array. You can certainly filter the list of tables `where table_name in (...)` though.

Comment: What ? Then what we put instead of `table_name` ?

Comment: `table_name` is a real column in the information schema. Try it.

Comment: Nothing happens! In fact I'm not familier with the information schema.  Do I need to change your code to use it ?

Comment: You got zero results? Try changing the database. Try looking up the documentation. Or just try `select * from information_schema.tables`

Comment: Ok, I will try `select * from information_schema.tables`. But that is a query into `mysql_query()`. How should I get the results ?

Comment: You should download SQL Developer or something that lets you run ad hoc queries.

Comment: I run your code on phpmyadmin, here is my output: http://uupload.ir/files/e0vg_schma.png

Comment: You're obviously getting something back. Try `concat`. Try `select *`

Comment: Well don't try `select *1 with a `group by`.

Comment: I tested your new codes, My new output is: http://uupload.ir/files/c8jc_schma3.png  I think it be better. But still has not been replaced.

Comment: Your code only works for `id` column. really I don't know why. *(According to the performance history of your code)*

Comment: Do you see the "..."? That means there more after. It looks like it cuts of at 50 characters. You seem pretty novice at SQL and you should take a little more initiative to play around with things.

Comment: I feel your answer is right, But I can't use it. +1 upvote for you ...!

Comment: The result of m query is a bunch of strings. Those strings happen to be update queries which you can reuse to as update commands against your database. If you can't even figure out how to see the output of a simple query then you need a lot more practice and you need to learn how to figure out how to do some things for yourself.